# OpenLayers readGeometry() method and reprojection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 6.3.5

I reproject features from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857` like this :

```
...
.then(tableauObjOpe => {
      const operations = []
      for (const operation of tableauObjOpe) {
        const feature = new Feature(operation)
        feature.setGeometry(new GeoJSON().readGeometry(operation.geom).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
        )
operations.push(feature)
}
```

Before, I tried for a while this code but I don't understand why it is not working following [the doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#readGeometry) :

```
...
.then(tableauObjOpe => {
      const operations = []
      for (const operation of tableauObjOpe) {
        const feature = new Feature(operation)
        feature.setGeometry(new GeoJSON().readGeometry(operation.geom),
          {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
          }
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bracket in the wrong place, `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` are options of `readGeometry`, not of `setGeometry`

```
    feature.setGeometry(new GeoJSON().readGeometry(operation.geom,
      {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      }
    ))
```